# Installing SSL Certificates for Wazuh-Dashboard

Tags: opensearch, wazuh

Is it possible to have Wazuh Manager served through custom SSL certificates? The wazuh-certs-tool gives you a self cert, and every other way to get it served through SSL has failed.

The closest I've gotten to getting this to work is I've had the dashboard being served by a custom SSL, I had agents connecting to it successfully and providing a heartbeat, but had zero log flows or events happening. When I had it in this state, I saw the API calls were coming from what appeared to be a Java instance, erroring out complaining about receiving certificate. I saw a keystore file located at /etc/wazuh-indexer. Do I also need to add the root-ca cert here as well?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your indexer's excepted certificates do not match the certificates in your manager or the dashboard.

If you follow the normal installation guide, it shows how and where to place your certificates, that are created using the wazuh-cert-tool. But, certificates can be created from any other source, as long as they have the expected information, you can check that information[enter link description here](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/user-manual/certificates.html) here.

I would recommend you follow the installation steps in the [installation guide](https://documentation.wazuh.com/current/installation-guide/wazuh-indexer/step-by-step.html), from scratch to make sure you copy each excepted certificate in it's place and that the configuration files for your indexer, dashboard, and manager take into account the correct files. All you would need to change, the creation of the certificates, to have your own custom certs.

In case of further doubt, do not hesitate to ask.